# How to switch to a dynamic array?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to set the size of an array to an input received by the program, currently the size of the array is defined as a `const static int`.

Board.h

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Board {
private:
    const static int BOARDSIZE = 5;
    char board[BOARDSIZE][BOARDSIZE];

    const char p1Symbol = 'R';
    const char p2Symbol = 'B';
    const char trail = 'O';
    const char crash = '*';

    int p1Row;
    int p1Col;
    int p2Row;
    int p2Col;
public:
    void setBoardSize(int size);
    bool isValidMove(int row, int col);
    bool isValidInput(char input);
    bool getNextMove();
    void initializeArray();
    void drawHorizontalSeparator();

    void drawSeparatedValues(int row);
    void displayBoard();
};
```

Main

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Board.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int size;
    cout << "Enter and integer between 4 and 20 for the BoardSize: " << endl;
    cin >> size;
    Board b;
    b.setBoardSize(size);
    b.initializeArray();
    b.displayBoard();

    bool done = false;

    while (!done) {
        done = b.getNextMove();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to use this function called `setBoardSize` to change the size of the board in the `Board.H` file. I've tried removing `const static` but then I get all sorts of errors. Apparently it isn't possible to define an array that doesn't have a predefined size?

Comment: If you are not allowed to use standard library containers for this task, I recommend making that fact clear in the question. If you do not, you will receive answers using nothing but library containers because that's the most-sane way to do it.

Comment: Use `std::vector<int>`  (if you're happy to have one dimensional indexing) or a `std::vector<std::vector<int> >` if you insist on two dimensions.  Either works, since `std::vector` is a (templated) resizable container of specified types, and can contain other resizable containers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `char board[BOARDSIZE][BOARDSIZE]` go for `std::vector<char>(BOARDSIZE * BOARDSIZE, 0)` and access elements as `vector[y * BOARDSIZE + x]` where x and y run within <0, BOARDSIZE).

You would resize simply as `vector.resize(size * size)`.

Comment: Good suggestion. A slight improvement is to wrap the vector in a data structure that makes it look 2D so you can't accidentally mess up the indexing in one spot without messing it up everywhere. [Here's a good example example wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301).